# Screenshot in Android same way as power + volume down button

Tags: android

Is there any way to take a screenshot in android using the same mechanism used when someone press the power + volume down button?

Basically I want to replicate the mechanism triggered when someone press power + volume down buttons.

I don't want to use the aproach below:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use the approach you listed?

Comment: This is not possible from a normal SDK app not running as root. There are plenty of posts out there describing how rooted devices can take screenshots.

Comment: I have issues screenshoting the MapView from google map v2 api but by pressing power + volume down button the screenshot works correctly. Thank you for the information!